# Clean software build directory after installing, on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu, make, build

Some Linux software needs to download, build (compile and link), and install for use.

The typical procedure is

- configure
- make
- (sudo) make install

For example, QEMU 4.0.0, which seems not available through apt-get, for now.

How could I clean up the build directory (> 1G)? Namely, how do I know what can be deleted, what cannot?

Comment: Have you tried doing ``make clean``?

Comment: After that, can I delete the build directory (not affect software's functionality)?

Comment: Hmmm.   I believe that you can delete the source code directory without affecting the installed program, but maybe you better wait for somebody else to come along and confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `make install` copies everything that is needed, so you can completely delete the source code direcory.

If this should not work for a particular package, I'd consider that a bug.